# How can I create a mysql_query that pulls items ranked using a Bayesian average?

Tags: php, mysql

Given a database table with the following fields:

- total_votes:  The total number of votes cast on this item/row
- average_value:  The average voting value (i.e. 3.6 with 5 being the max)
- total_value:  The sum of all the vote values (i.e. 3 votes of 4 will result in 12)

I was simply using a SELECT to grab the rows and the ORDER BY to sort them by their average value but then I ran into the issue of a good row with 10 votes averaging 4.9 getting outranked by a brand new row with only 1 vote of 5 outranking it.

After some research, I discovered that the most popular method of sorting rated items is to use a bayesian average.

```
br = ( (avg_num_votes * avg_rating) + (this_num_votes * this_rating) ) / (avg_num_votes + this_num_votes)
```

However, I'm having difficulty creating a query that pulls these rows and sorts them using this average as I'm a novice at creating anything advanced in terms of mySQL queries.

What I'm looking for is:

```
$results = mysql_query("INSERT ANSWER HERE");
```

Where `INSERT ANSWER HERE` is the answer you provide me with and `$results` provides these items sorted in by their Bayesian Average.

For more information about the Bayesian Average, I checked out: http://www.thebroth.com/blog/118/bayesian-rating

Comment: `$results = mysql_query("INSERT ANSWER HERE");` made me laugh

Comment: Ha ha. I'm glad that it brought you some joy. The little pre-question tips guide said to be thorough. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that you can get a Bayesian average with proper sorting with the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT *, AVG(total_votes) * AVG(average_value) + (total_votes * average_value) / AVG(total_votes) + total_votes AS score
FROM shows
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to use two queries. Perhaps this will do the trick

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    AVG(total_votes) AS avg_num_votes,
    AVG(average_value) AS avg_rating
FROM
    MyThings
WHERE
    total_votes > 0
```

This should give you the avg_num_votes for all items (that have at least one vote), and avg_rating across all items (again for those with at least one vote).

With these values in hand, construct query #2 and use ORDER BY:

**Query #2**

```
SELECT
    thing_id
    thing_name
FROM
    MyThings
ORDER BY
    (($avg_num_votes * $avg_rating) + (total_votes * average_value)) / ($avg_num_votes + total_votes)
```

Before submitting this query, replace `$avg_num_votes` and `$avg_rating` with the results from query #1.

Warning: Haven't tested this, and I'm not familiar with Bayesian ranking.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, mate, for the awesome response. I ended up writing a php script to post the average into its own field each time it gets voted on and a cron job to update everything every so often since the values will be changing as the site-wide votes grow.